# Why does Python's curve_fit not finish the optimization?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I need to find two parameters of an equation that best fit the given values of x and y.

I'm using Python 3, with Numpy and Scipy.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(dx, d50, p):
    return (1 / (1 + ((d50 / dx) ** p)))

xdata = [280, 150, 75, 45, 38, 20, 10, 5.1, 2.6]
ydata = [99.57592773, 95.53773499, 81.14313507, 67.08183289, 62.93716431, 49.961483, 37.80876923, 24.53152657, 13.2219696]

# curve fit:
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
print(popt)

I expect a d50 ~ 20 and a p > 0.
```

But Python send to me:

```
[0.00221498 1.60291553]

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:4:
> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
```

after removing the `cwd` from sys.path.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to obtain a good fit to your data using the equation in your post. My equation search found that a standard Weibull peak equation, "a * exp(-0.5 * pow(log(x/b) / c, 2.0))", gave RMSE= 1.619 and R-squared = 0.997 for parameters a = 103.1533969, b = 498.93546398 and c = 2.67321918 as shown below. I have included a Python graphical fitter using this equation and the standard scipy differential_evolution genetic algorithm module to find initial parameter estimates for curve_fit(), this scipy module uses the Latin Hypercube algorithm to ensure a thorough search of parameter space and that algorithm requires bounds within which to search. In this example, the search bounds are derived from the data. It is much easier to determine ranges for the initial parameter estimates than to find specific values.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings


xData = [280, 150, 75, 45, 38, 20, 10, 5.1, 2.6]
yData = [99.57592773, 95.53773499, 81.14313507, 67.08183289, 62.93716431, 49.961483, 37.80876923, 24.53152657, 13.2219696]


def func(x, a, b, c): # Peak_WeibullPeak_model from zunzun.com
    return a * numpy.exp(-0.5 * numpy.power(numpy.log(x/b) / c, 2.0))


# function for genetic algorithm to minimize (sum of squared error)
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = func(xData, *parameterTuple)
    return numpy.sum((yData - val) ** 2.0)


def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = max(xData)
    minX = min(xData)
    maxY = max(yData)
    minY = min(yData)

    minData = min(minX, minY)
    maxData = max(maxY, maxX)

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([minData, maxData]) # search bounds for a
    parameterBounds.append([minData, maxData]) # search bounds for b
    parameterBounds.append([minData, maxData]) # search bounds for c

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=3)
    return result.x

# by default, differential_evolution completes by calling curve_fit() using parameter bounds
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

# now call curve_fit without passing bounds from the genetic algorithm,
# just in case the best fit parameters are aoutside those bounds
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, geneticParameters)
print('Fitted parameters:', fittedParameters)
print()

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print()
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: one important thing, the data entry is not consistent with the equation, something that I realized later ...
the sigmoid equation requires that the values of y be between 0 and 1, ie divide yData by 100.
thus, the curve adjustment works well